# Strip everything until any number (0-9) is reached?

Tags: python, string, replace

How can I strip everything leading up to a number? Of course this would have to work for any number, not just 1.

I would like `blahblahblah 1 main street`  as input. And `1 main street` as output.

Comment: what's the desired output for `blahblahblah 1 main street 2 second ave`?

Comment: It would be `1 main street 2 second ave`. I'm okay with it splitting at the first occurrence of a number,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `re` module's `sub` function to replace all non-numerical characters from the left side.

```
import re

s = 'blahblahblah 1 main street'
re.sub(re.compile(r'^[^0-9]*'), '', s)

#Outputs '1 main street'
```

Comment: Worked! In 6 minutes I can accept this as the answer! Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of this :0

Comment: @hleggs Glad to help!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile). Drops everthing before a `'1'` (or any other number) is reached:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

s = 'blahblahblah 1 main street'
r = ''.join(dropwhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), s))

print(r)
# '1 main street'
```

Works with all numbers

Comment: Would that work if, say, the string was `text here 5 times square`?

Comment: I think the OP wants to stop at any num dynamically

Comment: While this may solve the specified case, it doesn't however address any numerical value dynamically

Comment: @MosesKoledoye where is your `t` variable in the lambda coming from?

Comment: @m_callens You should at least know that's a typo :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even simpler solution:

```
s = "blahblahblah 1 main street"

i = 0
for char in s:
   if char.isdigit():
      s = s[i:]
      break
   i += 1

print(s)
```

Just slice the original string starting from the point that you encounter a digit up till the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer, however I've already imported `re` for other uses :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go about doing this by a simple use of ASCII code. ASCII of 0 is 48 and 9 is 57. So you can do something like this:

```
str = raw_input("Enter a string:")
print(str)
stripstr = ""
flag = 0
for i in range(0, len(str)):
    if flag == 1:
        stripstr += str[i]
    elif ord(str[i]) >= 48 and ord(str[i]) <= 57:
        flag = 1
print(stripstr)
```

Comment: This copy only the numeric characters, halt the loop if you find a number and copy the rest of the substring

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. After it hits its first number, flag is set to 1 and all charachters following this are added to stripstr.

Comment: Yep you are right. I didn't notice that the flag keep it's value. Still the loop is executed for each character and the conditions are both evaluated. Still a really inefficient solution, don't you think?

Comment: I can change that with an elif statement. But I do see how Ito A's use of s[i:] is more effective.